# Reactive Forms checkbox bind to object

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

I have a formArray(of control type checkbox) which I am creating dynamically.

```
this.businessTypes.forEach(element => {
            const control = new FormControl(element);
            (<FormArray>this.businessInfoForm.get('businessTypes')).push(control);
          });
```

I am inserting the object as default value not just the boolean value.

Object :

```
{
    businessTypeId: number;
    businessTypeName: string;
    status?: boolean;
}
```

I want to change the checkbox input value from boolean to an object.status.

My control :

```
<input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">
```

But after un/checking the input, it outputs just true or false not the object.

Expected output:

**for checked:**

```
{
    businessTypeId: 59,
    businessTypeName: 'someValue';
    status?: true;
}
```

What modification should I make?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to push a formgroup to your formarray, a single formcontrol just takes a primitive value, not an object.

Comment: yeah, that's what i discovered. :/

Comment: Can how show me how you solved this, facing the same issue.

Comment: I could not find any clean solution. I ended up doing this manually, on checkbox click I passed the object and event value, then updated the main object.@user2960896